# Should be initial capacity of LinkedHashMap in abstract class always zero?

Tags: java, spring, class, attributes, abstract

From spring source:

```
    /** Map with String keys and Object values */
private final Map<String, Object> attributes = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(0);
```

Why initial capacity is 0? Default is 16, it is seems much more that in average could be used.
Probably average should be 3 or 4.
Does zero initial capacity in above code is related e.g. to technical nature of abstract class or there are could be other reason?

Answer (score 3):

If you are not sure that you will ever be putting elements in `LinkedHashMap` then it makes sense to initialize it to 0.

Initializing it to default size would mean blocking certain memory.